# how do you get rid of water inside a tire

Tags: tires

Broke the bead in a tire, it snowed on it, lots of water in it now.  I can't easily like reach into it, there's not much space.  I can't take the tire off easily.  Ideas?

No amount of resting it near a fire seems to be enough...

Answer (score 1):

I think it best to call a tire store and see what they would charge to do it. They can do a good job and do it quickly. If you broke the bead they may also identify if there are problems with the tire.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I laid the tire down flat, then used some wedges (tire irons from harbor freight in my case) to open up the bead a little on one side and also on the reverse of it.

Then I blew a powerful fan into one opening, so it'd blow through the tire and it the other opening, with maximum surface area of the the water to the air.  It dried out in a day or two I think.  No tire machine required...

If that hadn't worked I next would have tried cramming a piece of cloth in there pulling it out, drying it, repeat... :)

Answer (score 0):

Most common answer on the interwebs is to attach a shop vac to some kind of bendable straw and insert through the valve core, and hope it bends to the very bottom.  I'm not sure if this gets 100% of the water...